# Unable to schedule an ssis package WHICH RETRIEVES data from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, mysql-workbench, xml-configuration

I've created an SSIS PACKAGE on machine X to retrieve data from MYSQL DB Query from machine Y and write to an SQLSERVER Destination Table which is on machine Z(compulsions since I am unable to connect to mysql from Z and X is the only machine which has navicat).

The package runs to the T when run manually and I'm trying to schedule it on machine X for Z's DB .I've created the xml configuration file and placed it on Z since the process runs on Z's DB.and the job fails when executing as a scheduled Job.

I've added passwords to the config file as they don't save automatically.

I suppose it's due to different machines being used(Package on X running on Z's DB and config file on Z).

Here's the error:
Failed to open package file `"D:\CSMS\SSIS\Random\Random\MySQlDBtoDWH11DataTransfer.dtsx" due to error 0x80070015 "The device is not ready."`  This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of either providing an incorrect file name was specified when calling LoadPackage or the XML file was specified and has an incorrect format.  End Error  Could not load package `"D:\CSMS\SSIS\Random\Random\MySQlDBtoDWH11DataTransfer.dtsx"` because of error 0xC0011002.  Description: Failed to open package file `"D:\CSMS\SSIS\Random\Random\MySQlDBtoDWH11DataTransfer.dtsx"` due to error 0x80070015 `"The device is not ready."`  This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of either providing an incorrect file name was specified when calling LoadPackage or the XML file was specified and has an incorrect format.

Unable to understand where I'm failing!

Comment: does it use ODBC or ADO.Net connection to MYSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question,I've scheduled it to run from a batch file and the process is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Direct configuration or using Indirect( in which your xml config file path is saved in Environmental variable?

IF you are using Direct configuration, you need to make sure your both machines have the same folder structure which is saved in package.

If you are using Environment variable to point to configuration file. Make sure you have changed the value of variable according to machines and folders where your configuration file is.

Comment: @Bhupesh It's using an ODBC Connection to connect to mYSQL